# Angular. console doesn't show values of input

Tags: angular, user-input

Faced with the problem that console doesn't show input value.
just [task, Task, Task..]
but I need to catch input value and console it

**app.component.html**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="newTask.title" (keyup.enter)="addTask()">
```

**app.component.ts**

```
addTask() {
this.taskDataService.addTask(this.newTask);
this.newTask = new Task();
console.log(this.tasks);
}
```

**taskData.Service**

```
  export class TaskDataService {

  lastId: number = 0;
  tasks: Task[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  addTask(task: Task): TaskDataService {
    if(!task.id) {
      task.id = ++this.lastId;
    }
    this.tasks.push(task);
    return this;
  }
```

**tasks.ts**

```
  export class Task {
  id: number;
  title: string = '';
  isDone: boolean = false;

  constructor(values: Object = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `this.tasks` here in your code ?

Comment: You can simply JSON.stringify() the tasks to see all the data...

Comment: yes, to convert it into a string. forget about it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside html code you could use the json pipe, this shows the real value on the view.

```
{{newTasks | json}}
```